# Double negation in Reverse Polish Notation

Tags: algorithm, parsing, expression, evaluation, querying

I'm writing a boolean Reverse Polish Notation parser and evaluator. When I want to evaluate a double-negation, like !!A, the corresponding RPN is !A!, according to the [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). However, when I try to run the evaluation algorithm from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm) it fails, as, when the first ! is found, there is no value to apply the operator to, as expected.

However, if I write the expression as !(!A), it translates to A!! in RPN, which is what I would need.

Is it a problem with conversion to RPN, or a evaluation one? I could always fix it by enforcing parentheses with each negation, but that doesn't seem like an elegant solution...

Comment: The pseudo code in the linked article does not take unary operators into account. You'll need to modify it. Give a little thought to how you'd do that.

Comment: Yeah, I was missing the unary part, the only thing I did differently was to pop only one operand, but it wasn't enough. Thanks!